# Android BLE Background Discovery

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I recently attended an iOS meetup where BLE and iBeacon were discussed.  Apparently on iOS your app can receive notifications of discovery of BLE services in a passive manner.  That is, the OS notifies you when a new service (device) is in range.

Is there any analog to this behavior on Android?  I am familiar with both the classic scanning behavior on Android as well as the new `startLeScan()` on Android.  The problem is that both of these behaviors are considered "battery intensive" by Google and Google says to only scan when absolutely necessary.

I would like to be in a perpetual BLE scan mode for peripherals and other centrals the way that iOS devices can be.  Is this functionality currently available?  If not, has this functionality been announced for any upcoming versions of Android?

Comment: you can run BLE scan on android `startLeScan()` for an indefinite amount of time. It will work, but you need to know it consumes battery (same on iOS).

Comment: if connection is already build with slave device...n if slave is still live(only in this case) then you can ask to reconnect it with just additional property "autoConnection = true".

Comment: iOS connections never timeout, consequently if you hook your app into iOS correctly, when the peripheral that you attempted to connect to is back in range iOS will resurrect your app (if iOS killer your app) and permit the connection. I'm not aware this functionality extends to scanning. However sounds like Android does something similar with `autoConnection = true`

Comment: What makes you think iOS does anything different than what `startLeScan()` does for Android? The iOS BLE controller is also always turned on in order to receive notifications, so it is too constantly scanning, thus "battery intensive".